# Error in GridView CS1061

Tags: c#, css

This is the `GridView` code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="datagrid" runat="server" CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="datagrid_PageIndexChanging">
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the c# code:

```
string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DinoData.mdf;";
str += "Integrated Security= True";

SqlConnection c;
c = new SqlConnection(str);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
String req = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, c);
da.Fill(dt);
datagrid.DataSource = dt;
datagrid.DataBind();
```

The error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.manger_search_aspx' does not
>   contain a definition for 'datagrid_PageIndexChanging' and no extension
>   method 'datagrid_PageIndexChanging' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.manger_search_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So did you declare a handler named `datagrid_PageIndexChanging` anywhere in your code?

Comment: no i dont think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the attribute `OnPageIndexChanging` in your asp to `datagrid_PageIndexChanging` saying there would be an handler for the `OnPageIndexChanging` event.

If you don't declare this handler anywhere, you get this compiler error. So if you don't need/want that handler, remove that attribute from your `asp:GridView` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This message Always come up when you have this in your markup:

```
OnPageIndexChanging="datagrid_PageIndexChanging"
```

But no event handler in the code behind (like this):

```
    protected void datagrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something here to make it page, baby!
    }
```

So, either you remove the OnPageIndexChanging event from the markup, or add the handler in the code behind.